# Change the quality of an ImageView

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a splash screen, I'm doing that with react native, but I'm using android studio to create the style.

First of all, I'm following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8cl0v_tPog) that uses this [library](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen).

I have the following code of my splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_screen"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the quality of the logo is low, and I would like to make it better.

My drawable folder is the following:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't anywhere with your code or layout.  It's with the quality of the image you're providing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your **launch_screen.png** file has a small resolution.
Change that file with bigger resolution with better quality.